# Delete OneToOne relationship

Tags: jpa, reference, relationship, one-to-one

We have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private B b;

    @OneToOne
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

When we delete an object of class A it must not delete the referenced object B. At the moment we get an exception when we try to delete A because of the existing relationship to B. How is the correct mapping?

Comment: what is the error, and sql log?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable cascade delete

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {})
```

or you can try

```
@OneToOne(orphanRemoval=false)
```

Comment: Those options (empty cascade and orphanRemoval=false) are the defaults  when you don't specify them on the `@OneToOne` annotation so I don't think this answer will do the trick.